# Multiple word search with Solr

Tags: solr

I have a problem with Solr where I can't reconcile inexact search with multiple words.

Currently my Solr is configured thus: `query=ctnt_val:*keyword*` where ctnt_val is the field I'm searching and keyword the value I pass.

So if I type *lon* it will return all results with *longer*, *London*, ... which is what I want.

The problem is that if my query is several words long (e.g., *Gotham City*), it returns all results containing *Gotham* and all results containing *City*, instead of returning only all results containing *Gotham City*.

If I change the query as `query=ctnt_val:"keyword"` it works but then I lose the ability to do inexact searches (*lon* will no longer return *London*). If I do `query=ctnt_val:*"keyword"*` I get ALL results from my DB, which is clearly not what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The default search handler uses to have the OR as the [default query operator](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator).

You can check using `q=ctnt_val:gotham\ city&q.op=AND` which will set the query operator to AND and would make all the query terms as mandatory.

`gotham\ city` - `\` is to escape the space from the query

Comment: Weird... `q=ctnt_val:my%20profile` gives me 26 results but `q=ctnt_val:my%20profile&q.op=AND` gives me 0 results

Comment: are you escape the space. as q=ctnt_val:my profile, will search the my on ctnt_val field and profile on the default field and AND makes it mandatory for both terms.

Comment: `q=ctnt_val:my%20profile&q.op=AND` and `q=ctnt_val:my\%20profile&q.op=AND` give me the same result : zero :(

Comment: do the ctnt_val contain both the words ?

Comment: Yes indeed! The engine should find the results.